# Find the $\ker(f)$ and $\text{Im}(f)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider the rings $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}_{4} = \{\bar{0},\bar{1},\bar{2},\bar{3}\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{12} = \{[0],[1],[2],...[11]\}$. Define $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_{12}$ by $f(x) = 9x$.

1. Determine whether $f$ a ring homomorphism?
2. Find the $\ker(f)$ and $\text{Im}(f)$ if $f$ a ring homomorphism

**Solution**

1. Skipping all the details, $f$ is a ring homomorphism.
2. Ok, I always have problem with finding $\ker(f)$ and $\text{Im}(f)$. So, here I have found $\ker(f) = 4k$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

To find the $\text{Im}(f)$, this is what I did:

$f(4k) = \bar{36} = \bar{0} \in \mathbb{Z}_{12}$

$f(4k+1) = \bar{36} + \bar{9} \in \mathbb{Z}_{12}$

$f(4k+2) = \bar{36} + \bar{6}\in \mathbb{Z}_{12}$

$f(4k+3) = \bar{36} + \bar{3} \in \mathbb{Z}_{12}$

So, $\text{Im}(f) = \{[0],[3],[6],[9]\}$.  Are these correct?

Comment: Yes, these are correct. Good job!

Comment: Yes you're correct and you can check that by the fact that $Im(f) \cong  \mathbb{Z}/Ker(f)$.

Comment: @TimClark I am still learning that part.

Comment: Oh ok.  You're right nonetheless.  You'll learn about what I said soon enough I'm sure.

Comment: $x\in \ker f\iff [9x] = [0]\iff 12\mid 9x\iff 4\mid 3x\iff 4\mid x\ $

Comment: Thanks that's how I found the solution. I just didn't show it in here.